# How to make a function wait for other function's response?

Tags: javascript, rest, asynchronous, localhost

Below is a code snippet of my function:

```
app.get('/r/somepath',function(req,res){



    var s=req.params.a;
    var d=req.params.b;
    var date=req.params.c;

    var op=func(a,b,c);

    return res.send(op);
});
```

Now //func is a long function since it makes 3 GET calls to resful servers and then compiles the response and sends back to variable op.

But by the time response comes in op; before that only "return res.send(op);" executes and the response on `localhost:8080/r/somepath`
is empty.

How to handle this asynchronous nature.

Comment: See [Promise objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and / or [Async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: I found [this article](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5) very helpful for understanding how each concept works, especially in contrast to callbacks.

Comment: Thanks@ArmanCharan. will check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best way is to Chain your function calls using Callback in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Using Promise:

`var p1 = new Promise( function (resolve, reject) { ... })`

Wait for other promises to resolve:

`Promise.all([p1,p2,p3]).then(function (results) { ... handle results array here ...})`

Comment: can it be done using basic javascript and not jquery(^ If I am not wrong)

Comment: Promise is implemented in all browsers as of a while back, except for IE and Opera mini. So no Jquery required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6, you can use async await for this.